# Range$(M◦L)$ is a subspace of Range$(M)$

Tags: linear-algebra, function-and-relation-composition

Define the following linear mappings:

$$L:R^n→R^m$$

$$M:R^m → R^P$$

Prove that Range $(M◦L)$ is a subspace of Range $(M)$.

What I have so far (not sure if correct):

Range $(M◦L)=R^p$ and

Range $(M)=R^P$

So then I'd have to show that $R^p$ is a subspace of $R^p$?

Any thoughts on where to go? Thanks!

Comment: You can't say $\mathrm{range}{M}=\mathbb{R}^p$ because $M$ doesn't have to be surjective. The same holds for $M\circ L.$ Note that the range of $M$ is $M(\mathbb{R}^m).$ It can be zero, $\mathbb{R}^p$ or any subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\DeclareMathOperator{Range}{Range}$
$$
\Range(M\circ L)
= \bigl\{M\bigl(L(\vec v)\bigr): \vec v\in\Bbb R^n\bigr\} 
\subset \{M(\vec x):\vec x\in\Bbb R^m\}
=\Range(M)
$$

Comment: What can we do after we have that? We need to show this property holds under addition and multiplication right?

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as we know $\DeclareMathOperator{Range}{Range}\Range(T)$ is always a subspace of the target of a linear map $T$ the answer completely solves the problem.